# Why does @SuppressWarnings break my code?

Tags: java, generics, suppress-warnings

Got this idea from this previous question.

[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Anyway, my code is like this:

```
public class Slice<E>
{
    private E[] data;
    public Slice(Class<E> elementType, int size)
    {
        //@SuppresWarnings({"unchecked"})
        data = (E[])Array.newInstance(elementType, size);
    }

}
```

I deleted the unnecessary stuff. This compiles fine when the suppress directive is commented out. When I uncomment it, I get

```
Error: <identifier> expected    
        data = (E[])Array.newInstance(elementType, size);
             ^
```

Any ideas? why would this be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot put an annotation there.  It must go before the `public` keyword.  And you've mistyped the annotation name as well:  change `SuppresWarnings` to `SuppressWarnings`.

EDIT: If you were using an IDE like Eclipse, you would typically use the auto-correction feature to insert the annotation.  Naturally, it would be inserted in the right place and correctly spelled.

Comment: Just saw that in my comment right after I posted it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Long time no java for me, but you'd put that on the method, not just inside it somewhere, right?

Comment: In the other thread, they have it on the method like you're suggesting. I just tried that right now, and got this error:

cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SuppresWarnings
location: class Slice<E>
 @SuppresWarnings({"unchecked"})
         ^

Comment: Yeah, so you'll need to find the package that that class is in and import it.

Comment: @silky: no ... he'll just need to spell the annotation class name correctly :-)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this seconds after posting because I scrolled to see your answer :)